# Regarding threads and delay time

Tags: android, multithreading, delay

i have made this little code:

```
public class Game1Activity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private final Handler handler = new Handler();  
private final Runnable run = new Runnable() 
{
    public void run(){
        update();
    }
};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    update();
}

public void update(){
    try 
    {
        Log.i("update thread", "updated");
    }
    catch (Exception  e)
    {
        Log.i("update thread", "catched an exception!");
    }
    finally 
    {
        handler.postDelayed(run, 33);
    }
  }
}
```

as u can see, there is nothing special about it other than it writes in the log chat updated, **EVERY 33 milliseconds (30 fps)**.

here is my problem, if u can see from the log chat:

```
09-15 09:01:05.955: I/update thread(423): updated
09-15 09:01:06.025: I/update thread(423): updated
09-15 09:01:06.097: I/update thread(423): updated
09-15 09:01:06.166: I/update thread(423): updated
09-15 09:01:06.236: I/update thread(423): updated
09-15 09:01:06.305: I/update thread(423): updated
09-15 09:01:06.374: I/update thread(423): updated
09-15 09:01:06.444: I/update thread(423): updated
09-15 09:01:06.513: I/update thread(423): updated
```

the thread runs about every 70 milliseconds, double the time intended!
why does it happen? my thread is the most basic and simple it can be, i doubt it if there's something that can delay it

is there a better way to make it update exactly as intended?

Answer (score 2):

The processor need to switch contents for Threading. 33 milliseconds it is a bit low.

If you would use 300 milliseconds, that is an acceptable value for

```
handler.postDelayed();
```

If you want 30 fps, try and you have 30 millisec delay, than try with 1 millisec.

Comment: i tried even with 1000 ms, that is 1 second, and there is still a delay, it updates every 1020/1030ms. and so if 300 ms is the lowest how can i cause an app (a game) to update every 33 ms(30 fps)?

Comment: yes, there is a schedule time, than the processor need t switch applications and between application the threads ( task manager). Changing the running thread has an overhead, like 20-30 millisec, it will add more CPU usage for that switching task

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have used this code in my software code part:

```
this.timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
   public void run() {
      //do something here: probably update();
   }
}, 0L, this.INTERVAL);
```

it should be the same delay.

Edit:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
```

...

```
private Timer timer = new Timer();
```

the shedule documentation is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29). Versus other scheduling methods this should have focus on WHEN is scheduled, but I forgot where I have read that.  I hope one of this methods will help you.